# How to formally define this language?

Tags: formal-languages

Suppose we are given an alphabet $\{x,+,*,(,)\}$. I want to define a language of terms in this alphabet where outermost parentheses are omitted, multiplication and addition are done left to right, and multiplication takes precedence over addition. So, for example, $x$, $x+x+x$, and $x*(x+x)$ would be legal terms, but neither $(x+x)$, $x+(x+x)$, $(x+x)+x$ nor $(x*x)+x$ would be allowed. Basically, I want to know how to formally define a language where some operations are given implicit precedence over others.

Comment: Language determines what you see, not what you evaluate.

Comment: Also, your alphabet does not contain $y$ and $z$ yet you used them in your allowed examples.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you want to exclude $x+(x+x)$, $(x+x)+x$ or $(x*x)+x$. Or rather, you can of course exclude what you want, but it is unclear to me which _general rule_ you use to decide on words you want to exclude. All of these examples look like perfectly fine expressions to me.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Because, addition and multiplication are done from left to right and are commutative and associative, so I stipulate that there is no need to put parentheses in there.

Comment: @user107952: Where does "need" enter the picture? When you're defining a _language_ (in the mathematical, formal-languages sense), you don't care about _meaning_ or "doing" operations. What goes into the language is just a matter of _syntax_: some strings are in the language, others are not. You seem to be saying that some strings are not in the language. What is the principle for which strings you consider to be part of your language and which ones you don't?

Comment: Even if you don't want strings that (interpreted according to the usual conventions for arithmetic expressions) violate left-to-right evaluation, that doesn't explain why $(x+x)+x$ does not satisfy your criteria. That notation cannot really be anything _else_ than left-to-right evaluation of the additions.